# GCC Issue with Building an Old Linux Kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

I am trying to build from source version 2.6.37 of the Linux Kernel compiled for ARM. The reason I need to do so is related to work; I need that specific version. I am able to build the most recent version of the Linux Kernel for ARM with no problem. Here is my setup:

- Host computer is running macOS 10.15.6
- Running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on VirtualBox 6.1.14
- Downloading [this tarball of the kernel](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.37.tar.gz)
- `sudo apt-get install build-essential binutils-multiarch gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`
- `make distclean`
- `make ARCH=arm defconfig`
- `ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- make all`

This exact procedure works perfectly for the latest version of the kernel, but for this old version it yields the following output:

```
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  UPD     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  Generating include/generated/mach-types.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
In file included from include/linux/compiler.h:48,
                 from include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from include/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from include/linux/types.h:17,
                 from include/linux/page-flags.h:8,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:9:
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:90:1: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc9.h: No such file or directory
   90 | #include gcc_header(__GNUC__)
      | ^~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [/home/nick/Documents/linux-2.6.37/./Kbuild:36: kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:954: prepare0] Error 2
```

Investigating this further, I realized that the `include/linux` folder contains headers for `compiler-gcc3.h` and `compiler-gcc4.h`, but not GCC9 (unsurprisingly). So my understanding is that I need a version of GCC that's older than GCC-9. Next I:

- Appended `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the following:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb [trusted=yes] http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
```

- `sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated`
- `sudo apt-get install g++-3.4`
- <s>`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-3.4 1`</s>

<s>This, as far as I can tell, successfully installs GCC-3.4. Calling `gcc -v` confirms this.</s>

Edit: Instead of calling `update-alternatives`, I've now modified my MakeFile like this:

```
HOSTCC       = gcc-3.4
HOSTCXX      = g++-3.4
```

```
CC      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc-3.4
```

Where I added the "-3.4" to each line. I see how this is a better way of doing this, but I still have the same problem from here:

However, I now see the following output when I call `make ARCH=arm defconfig`:

```
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:118: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:397: scripts_basic] Error 2
```

I'm at a loss as to what's happening. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Change the GCC definition in your Makefile, or run a script to change your GCC definition , or add gcc links to your private PATH part ahead of the system parts, but don't change the system-wide compiler in use -- that leaves you one update away from the dreaded "update broke my system".

Comment: @ubfan1 Good tip, thanks. I've updated my question above. Unfortunately, that still didn't solve my problem. If I didn't edit my MakeFile correctly (I detailed what I did above), please let me know. I don't have much experience with MakeFiles.

Comment: You're closer to a solution than I am since you had a working current version.  I usually put the cross source/tools in one location, and run a script to define things like CC, CXX, RANLIB, STRIP, etc.  I added the cross tag to maybe get more relevant attention.

Comment: @ubfan1 do you mind sharing that script?

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here's the script I use for my ARM development of a web server on my Ubuntu Intel host.

```
MY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3
C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed
LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
#OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
#LD_RUN_PATH
#GPROF_PATH
#######
CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc
CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++
RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib
STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip
export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH
export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP
```

And another script, looks like for running the configure script for the web browser:

```
GCC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib \
STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip ./configure --build=arm-linux \
--disable-static --enable-shared --prefix=/mnt/usb/lighty
```

And here's the actual bin for that ARM code, I probably added the links myself for the short names, don't remember after so many years.

GCC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib 
STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip ./configure --build=arm-linux 
--disable-static --enable-shared --prefix=/mnt/usb/lighty

```
ls $HOME/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3/bin
addr2line                         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cpp        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gprof    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-size     cpp        gprof    size
ar                                arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld       arm-none-linux-gnueabi-sprite   g++        ld       sprite
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-addr2line  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm       arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strings  gcc        nm       strings
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.3.2  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip    gcc-4.3.2  objcopy  strip
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcov       arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump  as                              gcov       objdump
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib   c++                             gdb        ranlib
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++filt    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdbtui     arm-none-linux-gnueabi-readelf  c++filt                         gdbtui     readelf
```